# AttributeError: 'CreateBatchForm' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-forms

When i run the following program i am getting the error: AttributeError: 'CreateBatchForm' object has no attribute 'get'

I have tried changing the names of the objects and updated the arguments passed to the form "create_batch_admin" but it does not help.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [   
    #path('batches/create/', views.CreateBatchForm, name='create_batch_admin'),
    path('batches/create/', views.CreateBatchForm, name='create_batch_admin'),
]
```

views.py

```
import datetime

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from catalog.forms import CreateBatchForm

#@permission_required('catalog.can_mark_returned')

def create_batch_admin(request):
    """View function for creating a Batch by admin."""
    template_name = 'catalog/create_batch_admin.html'

    # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Hello")# Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request (binding):
        form = CreateBatchForm(request.POST or None)
        errors = None
        # Check if the form is valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            Batch.objects.create(
                batch_Name = form.cleaned_data.get('batch_Name'),
                start_Date = form.cleaned_data.get('start_Date'),
                end_Date = form.cleaned_data.get('end_Date'),
                time = form.cleaned_data.get('time'),
            )
            # redirect to a new URL:
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index') )
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/s/") 

        if form.errors:
            errors = form.errors

        context = {
            'form': form,
            'num_Batches': num_Batches,
             "errors": errors
            }

        return render(request, template_name, context)
    else:
        form = CreateBatchForm()
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
        return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

create_batch_admin.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Create: {{ batch.batch_Name }}</h1>
  <p>Start Date: {{ batch.start_Date }}</p>
  <p>End Date: {{ batch.start_Date }}</p>

  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
...
class Batch(models.Model):
    """Model representing a Batch."""

    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    batch_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter Batch Name', null=True)
    start_Date = models.DateTimeField (help_text='Enter Batch Date and Time', null=True)
    end_Date = models.DateTimeField (help_text='Enter Batch Date and Time', null=True)
    time = models.TimeField (help_text='Enter Time of  the day when the batch runs', null=True)

    BATCH_STATUS = (
        ('P', 'Planned'),
        ('A', 'Active'),
        ('I', 'Inactive'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=BATCH_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='',
        help_text='Enter Batch Status',
    )
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, help_text='More Details about the course', null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular student instance."""
        return reverse('batch-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.batch_Name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class CreateBatchForm(forms.Form):
    batch_Name = forms.CharField(help_text="Enter the Name of the batch.")
    start_Date = forms.DateField(help_text="Enter the Start date for the batch.")
    end_Date = forms.DateField(help_text="Enter the End date for the batch.")
    time = forms.DateTimeField(help_text="Enter the time of the day when the batch runs.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Friends i just figured it out that i needed to change the file
urls.py
from
this

```
   path('batches/create/', views.CreateBatchForm, name='create_batch_admin'),
```

to this

```
   path('batches/create/', views.create_batch_admin, name='create_batch_admin'),
```